# TFS Build Agent Issue

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We've just set up our first Build Agent with TFS to run unit tests on a separate server from our main build. This will be great but we have an error that doesn't seem to have a good answer:

**DLL has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.**

The DLL is of course a specific library within out project.

Anyone have experience with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out we were using the wrong build configuration. It was defaulting to a release build and this build had a requirement to run unit tests that were not being compiled.

Once we changed to a dev build with all of the projects included it worked perfectly.

All is well.